# simultaneously firing and events and location.path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, routes

We have a situation where we are utilizing a combination of events and routing inside  of angular to handle navigation and communication between modules.  Unfortunately the technique doesn't seem to work for us:

Neither this

```
    Events.identifierSearch.fireOnChange(symbol);
    $location.path('/explore');
```

nor this

```
    Events.identifierSearch.fireOnChange(symbol);
    $location.path('/explore');
```

Is working. The event handlers don't seem to fire.  However a less optimal solution that we tried to demonstrate our event handlers are properly connected seems to work:

```
    $location.path('/explore');
    $timeout(function(){
        var symbol = $event.target.innerText;
        Events.identifierSearch.fireOnChange(symbol);
    }, 500);
```

Now that is not what we want to have in our production code.  In reality the "symbol" will be a large group of nested objects, so passing them on the URL of a route isn't ideal.  And rewriting the routing seems like too much of a pain, it handles segregating partial pages nicely.

An idea i had would be to break this into two parts.  First fire the event AND handle the event in the controller that fired it.  This would require me adding a source  to the event - so no sweat:

```
    var controllerName = "thisBlahController" ;
    Events.identifierSearch.fireOnChange(controllerName, symbol);
```

then in the same controller, handle the event and fire the location change:

```
    $scope.$on(Events.identifierSearch.onChange, function() {
        var source = Events.identifierSearch.source
        if(source === controllerName) {
             $location.path('/explore');
        }
    }
```

Again - it is not ideal, because it uses the assumption that the event has been handled by all sources prior to the route changing.

**First**, it would be great to know what it is in the angular routing that is causing the defusing of the events?

**Second**, I would love an official solution to this problem, one that has been battle tested.

**Third**, failing a systematic solution, can would like to hear opinions on the two solutions I have proposed up thread.

---

Quick modification

If i rewrite the order using the timeout approach:

```
    Events.identifierSearch.fireOnChange(symbol);
    $timeout(function(){
        $location.path('/explore');
    }, 1000);
```

The functionality doesn't seem to work either.  Leading to question **four** Does a controller for a partial page, that is not the current ng-view get their event plumbing hooked up?